# Spanning divs and spans -- HTML5, css and WCAG

Tags: html, css, wcag

I have a three-column HTML presentation of courses using `div` and `span`. The goal at the end is to have a WCAG-compliant table, but I am stuck on a CSS issue...

Here is my code:

```
<div role="table" aria-label="TABLE-NAME" aria-describedby="TABLE-NAME_DESCRIPTION"><div id="TABLE-NAME_DESCRIPTION">WCAG HTML, hopefully</div>
<div role="rowgroup">
<div role="row">
<span role="columnheader">Course Number</span><span role="columnheader">Description</span><span role="columnheader">Prerequisite</span>
</div>
</div>
<div role="rowgroup">
<div role="row">
<span class="semester" role="cell">Fa1l, 1st Year</span>
</div></div>
<div role="rowgroup">
<div role="row">
<span role="cell">BUSI3333</span><span role="cell">Business 3333</span><span role="cell">Business 3332</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How to I make the semester appear centered?

[image]

At the moment, my working CSS is:

```
.annotate {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #366ed4;
}
.semester {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
}

[role="table"] {
  display: table;
}

[role="table"] > div[id] {
  display: table-caption;
  font-style: italic;
}

[role="table"] [role="row"] {
  display: table-row;
}

[role="table"] [role="cell"],
[role="table"] [role="columnheader"] {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0.125em 0.25em;
  width: 8em;
}

[role="table"] [role="columnheader"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: thin solid #888;
}

[role="table"] [role="rowgroup"]:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
</style>
```

Yes, I could put the semester in the center span with empties on either side, but that seems wrong.

Comment: Why are you not using an actual `<table>`?

Comment: Old advice was to avoid `<table>` because "reasons". The reasons are that people were using `<table>` for layout. If you need a table, it is semantically correct to use `<table>`. You know to not put CSS in HTML, because mixing concerns. But you are mixing accessibility (ARIA roles) and styling (CSS) concerns, the result is hard to maintain (changing the roles imply to change the CSS) and reuse (using the CSS imply to add the roles). Had you used `<table>` you would not need ARIA roles. Using `class` as interface between HTML, Javascript and CSS is ok. Also, for layout, please use `flex`.

Comment: You should definitely be using `aria-colspan="3"` on your `class="semester"` cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you should remove the `row` surrounding your `semester` span, and remove the `role=cell` declaration. Then it's just a plain old `span` in a `row-group`, and you can add `display:inline-block` to the `semester` CSS to center it. Like so:

```css
.annotate {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #366ed4;
}
.semester {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}

[role="table"] {
  display: table;
}

[role="table"] > div[id] {
  display: table-caption;
  font-style: italic;
}

[role="table"] [role="row"] {
  display: table-row;
}

[role="table"] [role="cell"],
[role="table"] [role="columnheader"] {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0.125em 0.25em;
  width: 8em;
}

[role="table"] [role="columnheader"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: thin solid #888;
}

[role="table"] [role="rowgroup"]:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div role="table" aria-label="TABLE-NAME" aria-describedby="TABLE-NAME_DESCRIPTION"><div id="TABLE-NAME_DESCRIPTION">WCAG HTML, hopefully</div>
  <div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
      <span role="columnheader">Course Number</span><span role="columnheader">Description</span><span role="columnheader">Prerequisite</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="rowgroup">
    <span class="semester">Fa1l, 1st Year</span>
  </div>
  <div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
      <span role="cell">BUSI3333</span><span role="cell">Business 3333</span><span role="cell">Business 3332</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Two good answers: Claire and Irin both aided me... This is the approach I am using, but Irin's was excellent, as well.  And regarding the inline discussion about using tables: I did... but our WCAG validator really does not like them and I get graded on our WCAG score... so I work on a computer, and get judged by another computer. But tables are easier in my mind, just not preferred in this instance.

Comment: You're almost certainly misinterpreting the WCAG guidelines if you're presenting tabular data this way, the [WAI-ARIA documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#table) say "As with other WAI-ARIA roles that have a native host language equivalent, **authors are strongly encouraged to use a native HTML table element whenever possible**.". As you're showing straight-forward data that's not widget heavy then the guidelines very clearly say you should use <table>.

Comment: @pbhj Understood... this approach is preferred by a WCAG validator... as an HTML coder, I prefer tables.

Comment: Which validator? Again, the approach of absolutely trusting automated tests [if it is one] , instead of using them as indicative, is a poor one IMO. I'd treat that result as being indicative of a false positive, a deficiency in the testing tool -- unless this is a homework exercise you should trust the guidelines more than a tool designed to test if things match the guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Just make your odd class display: flex and justify-content: center; to make the text center.replace this code with your code.

```
[role="table"] [role="rowgroup"]:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.annotate {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #366ed4;
}

.semester {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
}

[role="table"] {
  display: table;
}

[role="table"]>div[id] {
  display: table-caption;
  font-style: italic;
}

[role="table"] [role="row"] {
  display: table-row;
}

[role="table"] [role="cell"],
[role="table"] [role="columnheader"] {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0.125em 0.25em;
  width: 8em;
}

[role="table"] [role="columnheader"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: thin solid #888;
}

[role="table"] [role="rowgroup"]:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div role="table" aria-label="TABLE-NAME" aria-describedby="TABLE-NAME_DESCRIPTION">
  <div id="TABLE-NAME_DESCRIPTION">WCAG HTML, hopefully</div>
  <div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
      <span role="columnheader">Course Number</span><span role="columnheader">Description</span><span role="columnheader">Prerequisite</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
      <span class="semester" role="cell">Fa1l, 1st Year</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
      <span role="cell">BUSI3333</span><span role="cell">Business 3333</span><span role="cell">Business 3332</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```